# passing String object with "0x.." value as bytes32 to a solidity function

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, testing, bytes

I'm having trouble to pass bytes32  to a solidity function from javascript. It's converting to an incorrect bytes32 in solidity.
The javascript is a test, running with truffle v3.3.1 on testRPC v3.0.5.

```
MyContract {


  event myEvent(bytes32 id);
  function myTran(bytes32 arg) {
     myEvent(arg);
  }
}
```

When I pass it a string it works (and myEvent emits a correct hex):

```
myContract.myTran( "0x2a1acd26847576a128e3dba3aa984feafffdf81f7c7b23bdf51e7bec1c15944c");
```

this works too:

```
var x = "0x2a1acd26847576a128e3dba3aa984feafffdf81f7c7b23bdf51e7bec1c15944c";
return myContract.myTran(x);
```

This works but I i receive a different hex value from the myEvent than the passed hex:

```
 ... tx executed before  ...
    var x = new String( tx.logs[0].args.id );
    console.log(typeof x, x); // output: string 0x2a1acd26847576a128e3dba3aa984feafffdf81f7c7b23bdf51e7bec1c15944c
    return myContract.myTran(x); // executes but the bytes32 in the event is different
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a independent test case and it turned out the invalid opcodes were caused by something else.

Anyways, the outcome from my tests is that it fails only if I pass as a String object (it accepts it but converts the 0x0.. string into its ascii values).

Passed as String object .valueOf():

```
var testFoo = "0x341f85f5eca6304166fcfb6f591d49f6019f23fa39be0615e6417da06bf747ce";
var testFooObj = new String(testFoo);
return instance.sendFoo(testFooObj.valueOf());
// returns correct:
// "0x341f85f5eca6304166fcfb6f591d49f6019f23fa39be0615e6417da06bf747ce"
```

Passed as object:

```
var testFooObj = new String(testFoo);
return instance.sendFoo(testFooObj);
// returns incorrectly converted:
// "0x2230783334316638356635656361363330343136366663666236663539316434"
```

Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Bytes32Test {
    bytes32[] public fooStore;

    function getFooStoreLength() constant returns (uint len) {
        return fooStore.length;
    }

    event logFoo(bytes32 foo);
    function sendFoo(bytes32 foo) {
        fooStore.push(foo);
        logFoo(foo);
    }

}
```

Comment: Excellent!  Well done.  Good luck with the rest of your dev cycle.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried passing in the string primitive?

```
var x = new String(tx.logs[0].args.id);
return myContract.myTran(x.valueOf());
```

Comment: thanks for the tip.
with `x.valueOf()` I get:
`Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode` as well

Comment: I notice that you aren't indexing `q` in your `event myEvent(bytes32 q);`  And then you are accessing a formatted event result, specifying `id` with `tx.logs[0].args.id`.  Could you be reading the wrong argument?