# Convert hash function hex to bytes32

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, truffle-contract, hash

The output of hash function SHA256 is a hex string of size 64. For example: `3ed54831f488a22b28398de0c567a3b064b937f54f81739ae9bd545967f3abab`

I want to call the function of a smart contract with the following structure:

`function register(bytes32 hash)`

and pass the hex as an argument.

I use the web3 JavaScript library.

First I tried to pass the argument without any conversion. The result was a truncation of the last 32 bytes

Then I tried web3's `fromAscii` function with the same results.

I also tried `hexToBytes` and `bytesToHex` functions from the 1.x version. `hexToBytes` returns a byte array of size 32. When I pass the array to the smart contract function the results are totally different from the expected ones.

So how do I convert a hex of 32 bytes (64 character hex) in a format suitable for a `bytes32` function argument ?

I know I can use `bytes` or `string` instead of `bytes32` but I would rather avoid it as the hex of SHA256 is indeed 32 bytes.

**EDIT**

I create a test contract and test it in remix. I call `set` function with input `0x3fd54831f488a22b28398de0c567a3b064b937f54f81739ae9bd545967f3abab`. The value is not truncated and I get the expected results.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Test {
    bytes32 public hash;

    function set(bytes32 h) public {
        hash = h;
    }
}
```

So, the problem should be in the web3 library or JS itself right ?

**UPDATE**

I use the `truffle-contract` library to call my smart contract's functions

Comment: Total guess, but did you try prefixing the 'hex' string with '0x'?

Comment: Yes, I did for all cases. Same results.

Comment: I know it is not answer to your question, but if you are at the beginning of your project I suggest you to use ethers.js - https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/ Truffle contract and web3 really often has strange and unexpected behaviors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass it as a string
"0x3fd54831f488a22b28398de0c567a3b064b937f54f81739ae9bd545967f3abab" 
It won't get truncated.

If this not solve read this: [passing String object with "0x.." value as bytes32 to a solidity function](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19502/passing-string-object-with-0x-value-as-bytes32-to-a-solidity-function?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks. Very useful links. Passing as a string with prefix "0x" is not working. I tried the other methods but I am getting a out of gas exception.

Comment: Check all intermediate inputs and outputs on the console log, the error must be somewhere else

Comment: I was converting the input to bytes before passing it as: `web3.fromAscii(value)`. Removing the conversion and pass the input as `0x...` worked.